# Using webpack vendor bundle in a different app

Tags: angularjs, webpack

Ive built an angular app ("module") using webpack and bundled my app.js and vendors.js files.

The module works great as an app but now I want to use the module as a module inside a bigger ("host") app.

The vendors.js file bundles libs such as jquery, d3, angular, lodash etc.
I cant assume my hosting app would have these.

Now in the "host" app I need to load both the app.js and the vendors.js.

Is there some bundling technique that would allow to encapsulate the dependencies for my module? Or  some built in way (or plugin) to load the dependencies in my vendors.js such that they would not conflict with the "host" app's dependencies?

Comment: Did you already try and there were conflicts? Did you define any globals? Unless you did, there should be no conflicts.

Comment: When loading the vendors file it loads the libs inside as global (e.g. window.angular or window.$).